# How to compare 2 dates taken from datetimepicker in select query?

Tags: c#

I have 2 datetimepickers. In my select query i want to fetch records between these dates.  datatype for date in database in varchar(MAX). For datetimepicker i have set custom format as dd-MM-yyyy. Here is my sql query

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select custname From tb_customer WHERE date >= '"+dtp_fromdate.Text+"' AND date <= '"+dtp_todate.Text+"'", con);
```

For eg: if my start date is 9-06-2012 and to date is 11-06-2012. With the above query it shows me record for 10-06-2012 and 11-06-2012

Incase if my start date is 10-06-2012 and to date is 11-06-2012. With the above query it shows me record for 10-06-2012 and not 11-06-2012

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Use [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) or `Cast` T-SQL to convert `VARCHAR` value to `Date` or `DateTime` and also learn/use parameters instead of hard-coded SQL string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in lack of use of parameters. Using parameters will avoid any minsunderstanding between you and yuor database backend

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    string query = "Select custname From tb_customer WHERE date >= @from AND date <= @to"
    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, con);
    da.SelectCommand.AddWithValue("@from" , dtp_fromdate.Value);
    da.SelectCommand.AddWithValue("@to" , dtp_to.Value);
    da.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
}
```